# Android Autofill performed callback

Tags: android, autofill

I'm having issue with [Autofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize) framework. I have a LinearLayout with 3 input fields

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextInputLayout>
     <TextInputEditText
       android:autofillHints="personGivenName" />
  </TextInputLayout>

  <TextInputLayout>
     <TextInputEditText
       android:autofillHints="personFamilyName" />
  </TextInputLayout>

  <TextInputLayout>
     <TextInputEditText
       android:autofillHints="emailAddress" />
  </TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem here is that Autofill, when selecting either of fields for given or family name only fills out the name and won't fill the email address as well.

Is there any way how to check if given or family name were filled out using autofill framework and then focus into email field automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use autofill callbacks [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager.AutofillCallback)